# powershell execute appcmd with /IN < pathToFile

Tags: powershell, appcmd

I in the process of building a ps1 file to create all my IIS site(s), Virtual Directories and app pools via appcmd.  I have used the appcmd list /xml to get the settings from the master machine and saved them into config files.  What I am trying to get powershell to execute an appcmd command

```
  appcmd add apppool /IN < pathtoFile.xml
```

my issue is within powershell is I can not use the less than symbol:

```
PS C:\temp\deployments> .\createIISSetup.ps1
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
At C:\temp\deployments\createIISSetup.ps1:36 char:28
+     .$appcmd add apppool /IN < <<<<  $pathToAppPoolSettings;
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (<:OperatorToken) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

if I use the pipe:

```
  appcmd add apppool /IN | pathtoFile.xml
```

I get:

```
PS C:\temp\deployments> .\createIISSetup.ps1
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At C:\temp\deployments\createIISSetup.ps1:36 char:51
+     .$appcmd add apppool /IN | $pathToAppPoolSettings <<<< ;
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A colleague gave me the answer for this.  Just spun it on its head:

```
type $pathToapppoolSettings | .$appcmd add apppool/IN;
```

this works great.

Answer (score 5):

```
Get-Content appppols.xml | .\appcmd.exe add apppool /in
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you provide an answer, please explain what your code is doing.